# System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot find column [NameID].'

Tags: visual-studio, datagridview, textbox, dataview

I wanted to use a  search textbox to filter a datagridview in Visual Studio, where you will enter a certain primary key (i.e. NameID) to filter the results in the datagridview.  It throws the error which is noted in the title.

I have tried changing the code from NameID to [NameID] but this action did not work.

```
    private void TxtNamecSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dtvNames = new DataView(dtNames);
        dtvNames.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert    
    (NameID,'System.String') Like '%{0}%'", TxtNameSearch.Text);     //   
    Errror occurs on this line
        NameDataGridView.DataSource = dtvNames;
    }
```

I expect to type in the textbox, the primary key [NameID] which is a numeric number and the results in the datagridview will automatically filter by the column "NameID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not added the DataColumn named NameID to my DataTable, as this column name "NameID" is being retrieved from MySQL database and it is populated into the Datagridview. 
As a result, I had to change the code and this code, below, now works fine: -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class Form1
{
private BindingSource NameBindingSource;
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new DataTable
    DataTable dtName = new DataTable();

    // Add the NameID column
    dtName.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NameID"));

    // Create a new BindingSource
    NameBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    // Bind the DataTable to the BindingSource
    NameBindingSource.DataSource = dtName;

    // Bind the BindingSource to the DataGridView
    NameDataGridView.DataSource = NameBindingSource;
  }

  private void TxtNameSearch_TextChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
        // Set the filter
        NameBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("Convert         
  (NameID, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", TxtNameSearch.Text);
  }
 }
```